# Force sound Ringtone to external speakers even when there is a jack inserted to the device

Tags: android, notifications, alarm, android-alarms, ringtone

I am currently developing an app that uses the 3.5mm jack to capture temperature, one requirement is that, it should trigger a sound alarm once a certain temperature range was met. I have already have the code for the playing of certain alarm:

```
     Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
     Ringtone alarm = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
     alarm.play();
```

Now, my question is: How can I force this sound to the external speakers without doing anything to the functionality on the 3.5mm jack.